# Cassandra-backed persistence layer for ActiveMQ (Qsandra alternative)

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to use Cassandra for the back-end of ActiveMQ. I noticed that on [an Apache Cassandra page](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/RelatedProjects) there is a link to a project called `qsandra`.

However, after going to the page https://github.com/ticktock/qsandra I noticed that the project 1) had not been updated in 5 years (as of this writing), 2) the link under 'Cassandra' in the sentence that says, "The keyspace defined here...", does not work, and also that 3) the Maven repo http://maven.shorrockin.com/ is no longer present; so some of the dependencies to use this software are probably not present. The list goes on for the broken links...

Additionally, the documentation is not written in enough detail for me to understand exactly what I need to do. I think the audience for the README.markdown was written for someone with a huge amount of experience with 1) Maven, 2) ActiveMQ, and 3) Cassandra.

So, is there a more well-maintained and easy Cassandra-backed persistence layer for ActiveMQ?

Requirements:

- Cassandra-backed persistence layer for ActiveMQ
- Free, open source
- Documentation available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra is not a queue, and using cassandra for queue like workloads is almost always an antipattern. The combination of immutable files on disk and replication will cause queue like workloads to incur extra overhead persisting deletion markers, which make Cassandra a poor choice for queues and queue backends.

QSandra is likely not supported because it does not work well in practice, because Cassandra does not support queues well in practice. You are trying to use Cassandra for something that it is not good at doing, and you should probably look for another solution.

The fact that it's still listed on the Apache page is likely an oversight, and you can probably open a ticket on the Apache Cassandra Jira page to have it removed.